# Arcing during dynamic braking in AC single phase series wound motor

Tags: motor, circuit-protection

My 240 V 800 W hedge trimmer starts and runs with minimal commutator sparking but arcs violently at the brushes on switch-off. When 'on', the DPDT switch routes power through field coils and commutator in series. In the 'off' position, the field coil/ commutator circuit is shorted to effect dynamic braking. In both states, a 0.22 uF safety capacitor is connected in parallel. Each brush lead incorporates a small ferrite rod wound with several turns of insulated wire, which I assume is a current limiting reactor. I understand that commutation problems are a common cause of sparking, but commutator and brushes look OK, and the current limiters show no sign of damage. What role, if any ,does the safety capacitor have during the dynamic braking phase?

Comment: Your motor is not an AC one but a universal (brushed series wound DC).

Comment: My hedge trimmers have so much friction , there is no need for dynamic braking, but the cap can act as a snubber on switch open